# Application or Object Defind Error

Tags: excel, vba, solidworks

I am getting an object or application defined error on the below line of the following code:

```
.Range("A2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Sort Columns("C"), xlAscending
```

In the following:

```
Dim Exl As Object
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

Set Exl = New Excel.Application




Set xlWB = Exl.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Debug.Print Dir(TxtPath & "\BOMTable_" & swModel.GetTitle() & ".txt")

'RENAME SHEET 1 "RAW"
xlWB.ActiveSheet.Name = "RAW"
xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Activate
Debug.Print xlWB.Worksheets(1).Name

'FORMAT AND COPY RAW EXCEL SHEET
With xlWB.Worksheets("RAW")
.Columns("A:E").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 15
.Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 10
.Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 50
.Range("A2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Sort Columns("C"), xlAscending
End With
```

The code is ran in SolidWorks and opens a text file to excel for editing. It usually runs as expected on the first try but after that I get the object defined error.

Sometimes the error is also "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" or Runtime error 1004 "The formula is missing a ranged reference or defined frame"

Does any know a solution to this?

Comment: If `Exl` is an Excel Application (different to the one you are running the code in) then `Columns("C")` will need to be `.Columns("C")`, but that gives me an error message saying that "the sort reference is not valid":

Comment: And, if you aren't actually running this code in Excel (I'm not sure what you mean by "The code is ran in SolidWorks"), are all your constants like `xlCenter` and `xlDown` set up correctly?  (I just found a [solidworks] tag, so added that to the question.)

Comment: Hi, I edited the code to show how Exl is setup. Is Columns("C") not already .Columns("C")? The code is for a macro which will be ran from a button in Solidworks.  The Solidworks part will output a text file and  the line Set xlWB = Exl.Workbooks.Open(FileName) will open this text file to excel. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Changing Columns("C") to .Columns("C") seems to have done the trick! thanks very much! A lot of time was spent trying to figure this out. Is there a better way to write this code so the full location does not have to be specified each time?

Comment: If SolidWorks uses the same syntax as VBA, then `.Columns("C")` within a `With xlWB.Worksheets("RAW")` block is the same as writing `xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Columns("C")`.  Putting `Columns("C")` without the `.` means it is just `Columns("C")`.  I have never used SolidWorks before so I can't say what its `Columns` collection will be, but in VBA the unqualified `Columns` collection is equivalent to the `Columns` collection within the active sheet within the active workbook within the Excel application object running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set Excel = New Excel.Application
```

to

```
Set Exl = New Excel.Application
```

Comment: Sorry typo on my part. Exl = New Excel.Application is what I actually had

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
.Range("A2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Sort .Range("C2"), xlAscending
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the syntax of SolidWorks (and what it uses as various defaults) but, in VBA, the lines

```
With xlWB.Worksheets("RAW")
    '...
    .Range("A2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Sort Columns("C"), xlAscending
    '...
End With
```

are equivalent to:

```
xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A2", xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Sort Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("C"), xlAscending
```

The `xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Range("A2", xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Range("E2").End(xlDown))` part is defining a range, and then applying the `Sort` method to it.

The `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("C")` part is also defining a range, which is to be used as the sort keys of the sort.

Because you are trying to use keys which are not part of the range being sorted, an error is generated.

You can resolve that particular error (which may, or may not, be the one that is causing your issues) by changing the code to be

```
With xlWB.Worksheets("RAW")
    '...
    .Range("A2", .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Sort .Columns("C"), xlAscending
    '...
End With
```

i.e. **inserting the missing period**.  That will then ensure that the sort keys are obtained from `xlWB.Worksheets("RAW").Columns("C")`.